# Uploading files using firebase storage

Tags: android

I am trying to upload files(pdf,ppt,docx) from local file using new firebase storage. I tried code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file , but got error.

Comment: Show your code and the error you got please.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        final StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child(selectedImage.getLastPathSegment());
        photoRef.putFile(selectedImage);
    }
}
```